# Troubleshooting frame expansion with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, expand, subclassing

My goal is for my nascent custom GUI application, which subclasses `tkinter.Frame`, to expand in both directions independently when its parent window is resized.  This worked when I first built it in a script using native `tkinter` classes only (see bottom of post for that code), but ever since I restructured it as a subclass (see first block of code below), it insists on keeping its original proportions when resizing.  That is, if I maximize the parent window, the main GUI frame expands diagonally only until it hits the bottom of the screen.  Then the rest of the window to the right is left as empty gray space.

My question is: What am I doing wrong in the class implementation that's causing this issue?

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZc6P.png) of the problem, and below is the code used to generate the GUI in the picture (excuse the ugly color scheme, it was just to help keep my frames straight when designing/debugging it):

[EDITED TO REMOVE UNNECESSARY CODE (in this part, more of it turned out to be necessary to generate the frame I was seeing than originally thought, so I couldn't cut that much):]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

class CharDbGui(Frame):
    # Mage character database object
    def __init__(self, root, database=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.root = root

        ### Broad layout into color-coded frames first ###
        self.rowweight(range(1, 5), [10, 40, 40, 10])
        self.colweight(range(1, 4), [25, 75, 25])
        top_toolbar = Frame(self, bg="green", height=50, width=1)
        top_toolbar.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=E+W+N+S)
        leftbox = Frame(self, height=1, width=1)
        leftbox.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        midbox = Frame(self, bg="white", height=1, width=1)
        midbox.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        righttopbox = Frame(self, bg="black", height=1, width=1)
        righttopbox.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        rightbottombox = Frame(self, bg="purple", height=1, width=1)
        rightbottombox.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        bottombox = Frame(self, bg="orange", height=1, width=1)
        bottombox.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=N+S+E+W)
        entity_type_list = ttk.Treeview(leftbox)
        entity_type_list.pack(expand=True, side=LEFT, fill=BOTH)
        sb_etl = Scrollbar(leftbox)
        sb_etl.pack(side=LEFT, fill=Y)

        ### Placeholder widgets ###
        mainbox = Text(midbox, bg="white")
        mainbox.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        reserved = Text(rightbottombox, bg="purple", width=1)
        reserved.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
        logbox = Text(bottombox, height=6, width=80, bg="orange")
        logbox.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

        ### Create buttons at upper half of right edge ###
        # Create frame to contain the buttons
        bwidth = 12  # button width
        b1 = Button(righttopbox, text="New", width=12)
        b1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="")
        b2 = Button(righttopbox, text="Edit", width=12)
        b2.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="")
        b3 = Button(righttopbox, text="Organize", width=12)
        b3.grid(row=3, column=1, sticky="")
        b4 = Button(righttopbox, text="Templates", width=12)
        b4.grid(row=4, column=1, sticky="")
        b5 = Button(righttopbox, text="Delete", width=12)
        b5.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky="")

        # Space buttons vertically
        righttopbox.grid_rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
        righttopbox.grid_rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
        righttopbox.grid_rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        righttopbox.grid_rowconfigure(4, weight=1)
        righttopbox.grid_rowconfigure(5, weight=1)

        # add self to root
        self.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

    def rowweight(self, index, weight):
        # Adjust weight(s) of row(s).
        if type(index) == int:  # Singleton case
            assert(type(weight) == int)
            self.root.grid_rowconfigure(index, weight=weight)
        else:  # Range case
            assert(len(index) == len(weight))
            for i, w in zip(index, weight):
                self.root.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=w)

    def colweight(self, index, weight):
        # Adjust weight(s) of column(s).
        if type(index) == int:  # Singleton case
            assert(type(weight) == int)
            self.root.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight)
        else:  # Range case
            assert(len(index) == len(weight))
            for i, w in zip(index, weight):
                self.root.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=w)

    def fillDefaults(self):
        # Placeholder values to test with
        self.root.title("Test Database")
        # Populate the list with some initial values
        initvals_etl = ["Characters", "Items"]
        for x in initvals_etl:
            self.tree.insert('', END, x, text=str(x))

        y = self.tree.insert('', END, "nums", text="Numbers")
        for x in range(100):
            self.tree.insert(y, END, x, text=str(x))

    def launch(self):
        self.root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    gui = CharDbGui(root)
    root.wm_state('zoomed')
    gui.launch()
```

And then [here is a picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtUSc.png) of what I *want* it to look like, and below is the non-class code used to generate it:

[EDITED TO REMOVE UNNECESSARY CODE:]

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

### FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ###
def rowweight(index, weight):
    # Adjust weight(s) of row(s).
    if type(index) == int:  # Singleton case
        assert(type(weight) == int)
        master.grid_rowconfigure(index, weight=weight)
    else:  # Range case
        assert(len(index) == len(weight))
        for i, w in zip(index, weight):
            master.grid_rowconfigure(i, weight=w)


def colweight(index, weight):
    # Adjust weight(s) of column(s).
    if type(index) == int:  # Singleton case
        assert(type(weight) == int)
        master.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight)
    else:  # Range case
        assert(len(index) == len(weight))
        for i, w in zip(index, weight):
            master.grid_columnconfigure(i, weight=w)


### BUILDING THE GUI LAYOUT AND WIDGETS ###
# Create window that frames all our pieces
master = Tk()
master.title("Test Database")

### Broad layout into frames first ###
rowweight(range(1, 5), [10, 40, 40, 10])
colweight(range(1, 4), [25, 75, 25])
top_toolbar = Frame(master, bg="green", height=50, width=1)
top_toolbar.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=E+W+N+S)
leftbox = Frame(master, height=1, width=1)
leftbox.grid(row=2, column=1, rowspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
midbox = Frame(master, bg="white", height=1, width=1)
midbox.grid(row=2, column=2, rowspan=2, sticky=N+S+E+W)
righttopbox = Frame(master, bg="black", height=1, width=1)
righttopbox.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
rightbottombox = Frame(master, bg="purple", height=1, width=1)
rightbottombox.grid(row=3, column=3, sticky=N+S+E+W)
bottombox = Frame(master, bg="orange", height=1, width=1)
bottombox.grid(row=4, column=1, columnspan=4, sticky=N+S+E+W)

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: You set the weight for the root, but you need to set it for the Frame. Change `self.root.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight)` to `self.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight)`, and the same for rows.

Comment: A total of 4 places need the `root` attribute removed.

Comment: If you're trying to troubleshoot "frame expansion", I recommend removing as many widgets as possible. As it stands, you've posted way too much irrelevant code.

Comment: In `class CharDbGui()` add this line `self.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)` and `self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)`. This should fix your resizing issue.

Comment: Ahhh, good catch, Novel, thank you. Accidentally overdid it when going back and adding the "root" stuff. I apologize for all the irrelevant code; I'm new here, new to Python, and because I couldn't spot the issue I wasn't sure what was relevant. I will try my best to do better in the future, and I will go back and edit this post to include just the relevant parts now that I know what they are. Thanks again for spotting that for me.

Answer (score 0):

Novel gave the correct answer to this question in the comments:

> You set the weight for the root, but you need to set it for the Frame.
>   Change self.root.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight) to
>   self.grid_columnconfigure(index, weight=weight), and the same for
>   rows.

I had gone overboard when going back and adding "root" to things in devising the class, and I didn't notice I had done that until it was pointed out in the comment.